# Total derivation with respect to time.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, economics

Good evening everyone, I am trying to get a good understanding of total differentiation versus time. The problem I can't understand is the following. Starting with the basic national income accounting identity that output is equal to the payments to the factors of production: $$Y=rK+wL$$ Differentiating both sides of the equation with respect to time and dividing by Y, one obtains: $$\dot{Y}=\frac{rK}{Y}(\dot{r}+\dot{K})+\frac{wL}{Y}(\dot{w}+\dot{L})$$ What are the steps to see this? Thank you to anyone who will help me.

Comment: Could you give us the source of this formula and/or the meaning of each symbol? Is there any additional relation between them that we should be aware of?

Comment: Sure of course. The first is an accounting identity, it states that the sum of incomes in an economy (labor incomes: w is the wage rate multiplied by the number of workers, L, and capital incomes: r is the interest rate, multiplied by the total stock of capital, K) must be equal to total production (Y). The "dot" over  variables denotes a proportional growth rate. It is from a paper called "Productivity Growth and Factor Prices in East Asia" (1999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation as you've written it currently is wrong.

By the product rule of calculus, followed by factoring of some common terms,
\begin{align}
\dot{Y}&=(\dot{r}K +r\dot{K}) + (\dot{w}L+w\dot{L})\\
&=rK\left(\frac{\dot{r}}{r}+\frac{\dot{K}}{K}\right)+wL\left(\frac{\dot{w}}{w}+\frac{\dot{L}}{L}\right)
\end{align}
If you now divide both sides by $Y$, then you get
\begin{align}
\frac{\dot{Y}}{Y}&=\frac{rK}{Y}\left(\frac{\dot{r}}{r}+\frac{\dot{K}}{K}\right)+
\frac{wL}{Y}\left(\frac{\dot{w}}{w}+\frac{\dot{L}}{L}\right).
\end{align}
If you now define $\widehat{Y}=\frac{\dot{Y}}{Y}$ and so on (if you see footnote 3, the author calls this a *proportional derivative*; this is something which mathematicians would call a *logarithmic derivative* because by the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dt}\ln(Y)=\frac{1}{Y}\frac{dY}{dt}\equiv\frac{\dot{Y}}{Y}$), and $s_k=\frac{rK}{Y},s_l=\frac{wL}{Y}$ (as in the paper) then this equality can be written in the form
\begin{align}
\widehat{Y}&=s_k(\hat{r}+\hat{K})+s_l(\hat{w}+\hat{L}),
\end{align}
which is what the paper actually writes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I am trying to close the circle. Now I can understand almost all the derivations of related problems. In particular the same relationship of above can be derived from a production function with either cost minimization or profit maximization. There is just one last step that I cannot figure out in the case of cost minimization, if you can help me it would be amazing. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445226/economic-calculation-problem-of-cost-minimization